# What are packages, crates and modules?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have read [Managing Growing Projects with Packages, Crates, and Modules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-00-managing-growing-projects-with-packages-crates-and-modules.html), but I still don't really understand the hierarchy. I know what is crate and that there should be at least one crate in package: max 1 library crate and 0 or more binary crates.

First: Assume I want to have both `lib.rs` and `main.rs` crates in package. How do I access/call functions from `lib.rs` in `main.rs`?

Second: when I create new library with `cargo new --lib library-name` it creates directory with that name and bunch of files there, the only way I figured out to call functions from that library in `src/main.rs` is:

```rust
mod some_library;
use crate::library_name::library_name::foo;

fn main() {
    foo();
}
```

```rust
// Filename: src/library_name.rs
pub mod library_name; // I don't really understand this

// Filename: src/library_name/library_name.rs
pub fn foo() { 
    // ... 
}
```

where I have the following hierarchy:

```
 - package_name
   - src
     - library_name
       - src
         - lib.rs
       - Cargo.toml
       - library_name.rs

     - library_name.rs
     - main.rs

   - Cargo.toml
```

Is it necessary for `src/library_name.rs` to have the same name as `src/library_name` library? I'm really confused.

Comment: In simplest case a module is a separate `.rs` file. But if you need nested modules, you create a directory and you add a `mod.rs` file that proclaims the _directory_ as a module. You can call code from modules of the same directory by using `use ...`. You can call code from upper directory by using `use super::..`. You can call code from modules of another module by using `use outermodule::innermodule::...`, but it will only work if the `outermodule` declares the `innermodule` as public (which is done via `pub mod innermodule;` in `mod.rs`

Comment: If you don't want to mess with files, only then you define multiple modules inside a single file by using `mod module1 { ... } mod module2 { ... }`. The logic of calling modules applies all the same

Answer (score 6):

It's a hierarchy of three or four levels.

1. **Workspace** (optional): At the top there's the [workspace](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html). A workspace consists of one or more packages. The `Cargo.toml` file is special and more or less only lists the workspace members.

   Workspaces are optional and used for big projects. Smaller projects with only one package don't need them. In such cases we can ignore workspaces. We have a package at the top and the hierarchy is only three levels deep.
2. **Package**: Then there's the [package](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-01-packages-and-crates.html). A package is what haves a real `Cargo.toml` file. A package can compile to crates.
3. **Crate**: A [crate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-01-packages-and-crates.html) is a library or an executable compiled from the package. A library crate has a `lib.rs` file as a starting point. An executable crate has a `main` function as a starting point. A package can compile to at most one library and several executables.
4. **Module**: Then there are [modules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-02-defining-modules-to-control-scope-and-privacy.html). Modules are the hierarchical way how Rust organizes *items* like `struct`, `enum`, functions and others in the source code.

And how to you use this to give items unique names?

Answer: A *fully qualified name* starts with the package, then a series of module names then finally the item's name.

An example:

`serde::de::value::StringDeserializer` ([see here](https://docs.rs/serde/1/serde/de/value/struct.StringDeserializer.html)) has as package `serde`, as module path `de` then `value` then the `struct` is called `StringDeserializer`.

And where's the crate?

The package `serde` has only one crate, the library. If you look at the package's `Cargo.toml` there are no binaries listed.

(People tend to be confused about packages and crates. Even sometimes I am not precise and say "the serde crate" when I mean the package.)

In short: A **package** is code under a name (for example `serde`). A **crate** is a library or an executable.