# Import function defined in "src" directory from integration test file located under "tests" directory

Tags: rust

I am having trouble importing the public `add_two` function I defined in `add_two.rs` over in `integration_test.rs`. Here is my project structure.

```
Cargo.toml
src/
    main.rs
    add_two.rs
tests/
    integration_test.rs
```

Here is my main.rs file, which defines main function.

```
//binary crate: it contains main function

pub mod add_two; 

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use crate::add_two::add_two; 

    #[test]
    fn add_two_and_two(){
        assert_eq!(4, add_two(2)); 
    }
    #[test]
    fn add_three_and_two(){
        assert_eq!(5, add_two(3)); 
    }
    #[test]
    fn one_hundred(){
        assert_eq!(102, add_two(100)); 
    }
    #[test]
    #[ignore]
    fn test_we_want_to_ignore() {
        //snippet of code that takes too much processing time! 
    }
}

fn main() {

}
```

Here is my add_two.rs file.

```
//library crate 

pub fn add_two(a: i32) -> i32 {
    a + 2
}
```

Here is my integration_test.rs file.

```
use crate::add_two::add_two; 

#[test]
fn add_two_with_two() {
    assert_eq!(add_two(2), 4); 
}
```

Here is my cargo.toml file.

```
[package]
name = "tutorial1"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
```

Comment: A binary crate can't have integration tests. You'd need to separate your package into both a library and binary. You can then run integration tests on items exported from your library portion via `use tutorial1::add_two;`.

Answer (score 2):

[Integration tests](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html#integration-tests) are used to test a library. They work as if they're another package that has your package as a dependency.

Your package only has a binary crate, so the only thing integration tests can do is run the compiled binary. However, you can restructure your code so that your test does work.

First, you need a `src/lib.rs` file. This is your library's entrypoint.

```rs
// lib.rs

pub mod add_two;
```

Then, in your integration tests, refer to your library crate by the name of your package.

```rs
use tutorial1::add_two::add_two; 

#[test]
fn add_two_with_two() {
    assert_eq!(add_two(2), 4); 
}
```

This will work as intended, but you should also cleanup `main.rs` so that it depends on your library entrypoint as well. This keeps code from being compiled twice unnecessarily.

```rs
// main.rs

use tutorial1::add_two;
// instead of `mod add_two;`
```

It's also sensible to move your tests into `add_two.rs` since they are only relevant to that module. This will also ensure they are run when you test the library.

Related:

- [What are packages, crates and modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64305657/6274355)

Comment: So, is "lib.rs" file a special name file in Rust to indicate is the file that will compile to the main library crate (a Rust package can have at most 1 library crate right?). And, by having the "mod add_two" statement, in my lib.rs file, the module "add_two" will be accessible from outside the library crate by referring to the tutorial1 package (since package encompasses the crates in terms of organizational hierarchy?). Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @user19417266 It's somewhat special. "lib.rs" is cargo's default/automatic library entrypoint. https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#library That's all correct, except `pub mod add_two` makes it accessible both outside *and inside* the library crate.

Comment: "Your package only has a binary crate, so you can't add integration tests to it" isn't quite correct — integration tests can *run* a binary. Cargo has specific support for this.

Comment: Ahh, you can test the binary, but you can't test pub items in the entrypoint module. https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-test.html#target-selection